# Recover overwritten JAVA file

Tags: java, recover

I was making a jar file but accidentally wrote `TimerV1.java` instead of `TimerV1.jar` and as a result, my whole source code **got replaced** with machine code and the sad thing is there's still something I have to edit.

I am using **Notepad++** and tried searching the `Roaming` directory but there's nothing there.

I also tried decompiling the jar file and editing the exported source files (with JD-GUI) but when I try to compile those source files I get errors that I don't even know how to resolve.

Is there any way to recover the previous versions of my java file?

Comment: Good time to start using git

Comment: @SashaSalauyou presumably it is just _after_ a good time to start using git

Comment: Do you have automatic regular backups set?  If not, then you now know why you should.  If you have, then recover the latest version from the backup disc/folder/whatever.  It probably won't be completely up to date, but it will give you a head start.

Comment: You may want to try a different decompiler.  I have had good luck with this one - https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler, there are also links to some other alternatives.  But as with the above comments, version control is your friend even for personal projects.

Comment: @rossum Unfortunately none. I just learned my lesson.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou to be really honest, I have no idea how to use git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JAD (Java Decompiler) but.. not all code can be reversed into source.

Try one of:

- http://jd.benow.ca/
- https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler
- http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/
- https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower
- http://www.javadecompilers.com/jad

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions

Comment: @FriencyLoriagaFernandez If helped, please accept this answer :)

Comment: I used another decompiler but still thanks. I gave an upvote instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Notepad++ myself but it seems there is a backup folder where older versions of edited files are kept:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup
```

Comment: I checked that but it's empty. >_< Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are various utilities out there that can recover deleted files, I think because typically they are still there but the OS lists that space as unallocated.  But overwritten files...I wish I had a better answer but I don't know if they can be recovered, unless some version was saved somewhere.

If it was a relatively short file, maybe the best thing to do is take this as an painful opportunity to use a backup service like Carbonite or Dropbox, and use version control like Git or SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I have used another decompiler and debugged one by one. Thanks to those who answered :)
I used [Cavaj Decompiler](http://cavaj-java-decompiler.en.softonic.com/).